# Linq: delete table entry with primary - foreign key relationship

Tags: linq, windows-phone

I have Windows Phone app with Table A and Table B has primary - foreign key relationship. I need to remove an entry from Table A. How do I do this?

Table A contains objects of type Shape and has field ShapeColor. Table B has objects of type ShapeColor.

When I try to delete Shape from Table A using DeleteOnSubmit followed by SubmitChanges throws an exception

> "{"The primary key value cannot be deleted because references to this
>   key still exist. [ Foreign key constraint name = ShapeColor_Shape ]"}

Comment: Could you show the code that executes the delete? Something must trigger the delete of the parent entry. Did you monitor the emitted SQL? Is the delete of `tableA` before or after that of `tableB`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
context.DeleteOnSubmit(EntityA.ReferenceToTableB)
context.DeleteOnSubmit(EntityA)
```

Delete the relationship first, then delete the entity, and submit the changes to the database.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the answer. If I have Shape1 and Shape2 in Shapes table both reference ColorRed in ShapeColor table. I want to delete only Shape1 from Shapes table and leave Shape2 as is.

Comment: It sounded like shape2 was related to shape1, and in that scenario, you'd have to delete both entities, or remap the pointer of shape2 to shape1 to something else.  In your scenario, you would only have to delete shape1, but the error your getting indicates otherwise.  You have a primary key reference to something that needs to be pointed to something else, or the foreign key entity needs removed....